# Регулярное выражение для поиска нескольких чисел через разделитель (тире)

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

У меня есть артикулы товаров 11-3233 и 11-8232-99, и я хочу, чтобы регулярное выражение распознавало эти артикулы, то есть вывод должен быть такой:

```
[('11-3233', '11-8232-99')]
```

Мой код:

```
r = '(([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*))|(([0-9]*)-([0-9]*))'
re.findall(r, 'мне нужен товар 11-3233 и 11-8232-99')
```

Выполнив этот код у меня выводит:

```
[('', '', '', '', '11-3233', '11', '3233'),('11-8232-99', '11', '8232', '99', '', '', '')]
```

Как изменить код так, чтобы я получал только свои артикулы без лишних компонентов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)` — `*` означает 0 или много совпадений. Т.е. их вообще может не быть, и в список может случайно попасть строка `"-"`. Вместо звездочек, там должны быть `+` означающие «1 или больше»

---

`r'\d+(?:-\d+){1,2}'`: `\d` — цифра (**d**igit), `+` один или больше раз подряд, `?:` — «не группа захвата», `-\d+` тире и еще числа, `{1,2}` от 1 до 2 (включительно) штук.

```
import re

regex = r'\d+(?:-\d+){1,2}'
match = re.findall(regex, 'мне m-m нужен товар 11-3233 и 11-8232-99 1-1-1-1')

print( match ) # ['11-3233', '11-8232-99', '1-1-1']
```

Если случай с обрезанным `1-1-1` не предусматривался, можно взять `r'\d+(?:-\d+)+'` такую регулярку которая "съест" любые цепочки чисел, а из результатов отфильтровать те, в которых 1 или 2 `-`

Или, усложнить выражение `r'(?<!\d-)\d+(?:-\d+){1,2}(?!-\d)'` где `(?<!)` «negative lookbehind» и `(?!)` «negative lookahead»,  обеспечивают отбрасывание всего, что совпадает с исходной регуляркой, но имеет «хвост» в виде дополнительного числа с тире.

(вроде ручная фильтрация списка результатов будет приятнее, чем такие регулярки)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение!
Убрал все круглые скобки и получил нужный ответ!

```
r = '[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*|[0-9]*-[0-9]*'
re.findall(r, 'мне нужен товар 11-3233 и 11-8232-99')
```

Comment: Вы молодец, что сами решили, но я бы заменил `[0-9]` на `\d`, а для поиска использовал вместо `*` символ `+`, т.е. `[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*|[0-9]*-[0-9]*` -> `\d+-\d+-\d+|\d+-\d+`